# Sort coordinates as per polygon in excel or through QGIS

Tags: java, excel, coordinates, gis

I have a list of our sales lead locations in excel with their coordinates.

What I wish to do is that I need to sort those coordinates as per the condition if they lie within a certain polygon or not. So suppose I have 2 polygons for 2 cities then I need to mark the coordinates in the sheet like they’re in polygon 1 or 2 or NIL.

I had been doing this manually in QGIS by selecting the outside points and deleting them and then exporting and then again sorting the sheet but this is now taking a lot of time since the number of entries is increasing.

Could someone suggest a better, simpler and quicker way to do this, irrespective of the method used. I don’t much care if as per your suggestion it can be done in excel itself or in QGIS or with the help of some other software. I just need to mark in the next column that to which polygon the coordinates belong.

Example :

Input

| Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- |
| 19.062892 | 72.882464 |
| 28.630800 | 77.233433 |

Output

| Latitude | Longitude | Polygon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19.062892 | 72.882464 | Mumbai |
| 28.630800 | 77.233433 | Delhi |

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using a geo-enabled database like MongoDB?  It's easy to set up and you can probably find the city lat/lon polygons online somewhere.

Comment: Yes that's like the actual correct way to do for large scale but I do not have experience in programming so didn't emphasise on it much. Hence was searching for some other methods.